# Regex and split/replace VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

I get this value by Regex 
`<a href="http://www.site.com/path/index.php" class="visio_large" target=""><span>Click here</span></a>`

How can I get the URL "http://site.com/path/index.php"(without quotes) and leave all rest of the value

Comment: I would use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse html (always worth "reading": http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284240).

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding parsing HTML with Regex.

But if you're sure about the cleanliness of the HTML and you need a quick hack, then you could use this regex:

`/<a href="(.+)">/`

Build it using `New Regex()` and match with `.Match()` and get the value with `.Value`

Comment: Sorry but i couldn't figure out how to do it , can you please show me an example ?